# pass the data and display that model

Tags: ios, swift, model

I have done search the tableview using `MVVM` in swift.

I have total 3 screen:

1. foodlist - I have `Model`, `DataSourceModel`, `ViewModel` and `ViewController`
2. menulist - I have `Model`, `DataSourceModel`, `ViewModel` and `ViewController`
3. searchinglist - I have `Model`, `DataSourceModel`, `ViewModel` and `ViewController`

Now while clicking the searched text from the `TableView` I need to view the data.

example:-
searching text is -a name of food(Rice and egg)

Rice and egg is in the foodlist. So I need to display that `ViewController`.

So for that, how can I init the model in the searchinglist?

My foodlistmodel in this way:-

```
class foodModel: NSObject {

var name :String!
var location:String!
var imageurl :String!
var date:String!
var place:String!

init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

    guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,

        let location = dictionary["location"] as? String,
        let imageurl = dictionary["imageurl"] as? String,
        let date  = dictionary["date"] as? String,
        let place = dictionary["place"] as? String else {
            return
    }

    self.name = name
    self.location = location

    self.imageurl = imageurl
    self.place = place
    self.date = date
}  
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but **never** declare properties in a class as IUO which are going to be initialized in an `init` method. If the properties are supposed to be optional declare them as regular optional (`?`), otherwise as non-optional.

Comment: @vadian how to init the foodlist model to the searchinglist model

Comment: @nahlaabdulnawal create an object of your foodlist model in your searchinglist model

Comment: @AshishBahl how and how to init the foodlist .Can u please show it

Comment: @AshishBahl please can u show the solution

Answer (score 0):

Create an object for your **Foodlist** model in **Searchinglist** model.

```
let searchModel = Foodlist(dictionary : yourDict)
```